# Ayuda en CMDLET para realizar inventario del ActiveDirectory

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, windows-server-2012

Estoy realizando un inventario de equipos de AD y los campos que requiero son **HostName**, **Serie** y **Modelo** del equipo en cuestión, pero estos datos esta divididos entre `Win32_Computersystem` y `Win32_Bios` por lo que me veo obligado a usar estos dos CMDLETS que logre crear;

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter{Name -like "tdlim*"} | select -ExpandProperty Name | foreach {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_} | Format-Table Name, Model

Get-ADComputer -Filter{Name -like "tdlim*"} | select -ExpandProperty Name | foreach {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_} | Format-Table SerialNumber
```

Lo que quisiera es fusionar los dos CMDLETS de manera que pueda obtener en una tabla el HostName, el Serial y el Modelo de los equipos.

Gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías generar un objeto PSObject donde se agrega una columna por propiedad, de la siguiente manera:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter{Name -like "tdlim*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $ourObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $ourObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    $ourObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model)
    $ourObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber)
    $ourObject
}
```

Y así como resultado se genera una tabla con todos los datos de todos los equipos que filtras en el inicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo y te cuento como me va.

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, le añadí $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue' para que no me llenara la pantalla de errores y me sirvió bastante, gracias.